# Rails 3 app not accessing jqtouch js and css files

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile, jqtouch

My app doesn't seem to be accessing the js and css files for jqtouch.

in my layout file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "/jqtouch/src/lib/jquery-1.7.js", "/jqtouch/src/jqtouch-jquery.js", "mobile" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/jqtouch/css/jqt.css", "/jqtouch/themes/css/jqtouch.css" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

file locations: (added downloaded jqtouch-1.0-b4-rc directory to public without changing any file locations and then renamed the directory to jqtouch)

```
public/jqtouch/src/lib/jquery-1.7.js
public/jqtouch/src/jqtouch-jquery.js
public/javascripts/mobile.js

public/jqtouch/css/jqt.css
public/jqtouch/themes/css/jqtouch.css
```

in public/javascripts/mobile.js file:

```
$.jQTouch({
    statusBar: 'yellow'
});
```

in my index.mobile.erb file:

```
<ul>
    <li class="arrow">blah blah</li>
    <li class="arrow">yada yada</li>
    <li class="arrow">foo blarney</li>
</ul>
```

my understanding is that with the above configuration the page should be rendered like an iPhone app. it's not.

thanks for your help.

UPDATE: I tried using jquery mobile. I placed the js file in public/javascripts and the css file in public/stylesheets and everything worked. I placed the jqtouch js and css files similarly and got rid of all the bloat but it still did not work. My answer may be to just switch to jquery mobile.

Comment: Question about the question: Is vendor/assets now the 'correct' place for assets like this? Spent some time getting that to work myself today... (but unfortunately I don't know enough to answer your question with any confidence. Sorry.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while and no answers. I've put enough time into this and have decided to move on to jquery mobile.

Answer (score 0):

This rails 3 project on github should help. I managed to get it running locally in just a few moments and browse it on iOS Simulator. It works a treat.

https://github.com/vincentpaca/Rails-3-Mobile

The rails guide to asset pipeline was also a good resource:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html